# Flutter Color Circular Border

Tags: flutter

i have the code below and an attached image. how do i round the corners of the circled parts of the image? i have tried to round the corner of the image and the bottom parts of the container but am unable to achieve a smooth circular border. tia

```
class NewsCardWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final News news;

  const NewsCardWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.news,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.black,
          width: 10,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        color: Colors.white,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
            spreadRadius: 3,
            blurRadius: 7,
            offset: const Offset(0, 3),
          )
        ],
      ),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: news.image != ''
                    ? DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage('${news.image}'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      )
                    : const DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/image/newspaper.png'),
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add clip = Clip.antialias to container and add rounded rectangle border to the same container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the Container widget containing your image with a [ClipRRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html), add a padding to the parent container to create the border effect and change the color to black.

```
class NewsCardWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final News news;

  const NewsCardWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.news,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        color: Colors.black,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
            spreadRadius: 3,
            blurRadius: 7,
            offset: const Offset(0, 3),
          )
        ],
      ),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
              child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/don.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is how it looks like.

[image: This is how it looks like]

Comment: thank you so much for this! was able to configure to how i wanted it to look like